# Multiple scans/intents delivered to receiving Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I have an ongoing problem where my app is delivering multiple intents to the recieving Activity after an NFC tag scan.

My App essentially scans an NFC tag which has some data on it and sends it to the server.
In general it works fine. I understand that NFC works within a threshold of a few cms and perhaps my problem is user error, for example the user is waving the phone around the tag which could scan it twice within millisecs.

I have put a timer in the Application object. When the user scans a tag, i start the timer going and set a flag to false, this flag is checked within the Activity that handles the NFC intent and the the intent is dropped if the flag is false. This (should) stop multiple scans of a tag within 10 secs.

My app is used for HomeCare work, so a user will scan a tag in the clients house. When they scan the tag the first time it logs them in at that client with data and a time stamp. The second scan of the tag will log them out.

In general it works but sometimes a carer will log in and out at the first client, then at the second client or sometimes hours later, the carer will be logged back in at the previous client.

What i think is happening is the carer is mis-scanning the tag which is triggering the NFC adpter twice. The first intent is delivered straight away, then the second is delivered minutes/hours later.

How things flow.
scan tag  -> intent delivered to Activity -> start AppObj timer.
write data to sqlite DB -> start an IntentService to send the transaction to server(cancelled after 10 seconds).

Can anyone see a problem i've missed that could account for why a duplicate Intent is delivered hours later?

Can anyone suggest a solution which would stop this happening?

Is there a problem whith how the intent is handled in the activity? eg the wrong code in the wrong Activity lifecycle method?

Is there a way to cancel/intercept the second intent from the second mis-scan?

Basically, what i want is that the nfcAdapter could be triggered 10 times in one second, but only the first scan is delivered to the activity. How can i achieve this?

i'll post some code.

[edit2]

```
Toast.makeText(this, "about to test flags", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "intent is from history", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(this, "intent is not from history", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

.

[edit3]

```
<activity
            android:name=".NfcscannerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.QRCODE_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".EntryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.INVALID_CARER_TAG_SCANNED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

.
[edit4]

```
Tag tagTest = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

            Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tagTest);

            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "about to test io operations on Ndef Tag");
                ndefTag.connect();  // this should already perform an IO operation and should therefore fail if there is no tag
                NdefMessage ndefMsg = ndefTag.getNdefMessage(); // this reads the current NDEF message from the tag and consequently causes an IO operation
                Log.e(TAG, "tested io operations on Ndef Tag, must be a real Tag!!!!!******!!!!!!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // there is no tag or communication with tag dropped
                Log.e(TAG, "tested io operations on Ndef Tag, No Tag there, must be a re-delivery of the old Tag via an intent!!!!!******!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                onResume();
            } finally {
                try {
                    ndefTag.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
```

Comment: You code does not make much sense (unbalanced brackets, `} else { Log.e(TAG, "ndef not discovered!!!!!!"); }` without a matching `if ... {`. Please post your correct (and **properly formatted**) code.

Comment: Also, are you only processing intents in `onCreate` or do you also perform any processing in `onStart` or `onResume`?

Comment: @Michael Roland Hi, i've posted the full NFC relevant part of my onCreate(). I only process intents in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you describe, I would assume that your affected users "close" (actually *hide*) the app by pressing the home key. Later they are opening the app (or rather that activity) from the history (long-press home key).

Assuming that you process the NFC-related intents *only* in `onCreate()`, you would normally not run into the issue you described when starting your activity from the history as the `onCreate()` method would not be called if your activity still existed in the background. **But** if your activity has been destroyed meanwhile (e.g. app has been manually killed, app has been killed by the system to free resources, etc), re-launching the app from the history will cause your `onCreate()` method to be run again. As Android rebuilds the activity stack and re-sends the **original intents** (i.e. the intent that initially launched your activity) again when opening apps from the history, you activity will receive the NFC intent that it had received when it was initially started.

You can overcome this problem by checking if the intent you receive has the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` set. This would be the case *only* if your activity was started from the history.

```
if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0) {
     if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) ||
         NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

Not solving your initial problem but as a last resort, remember that NFC tags can be accessed by IO operations after receiving an intent. So in order to check if the tag you receive in the intent actually exists, you could perform such an IO operation.

If, for instance, your tag is an NDEF tag:

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);

try {
    ndefTag.connect();  // this should already perform an IO operation and should therefore fail if there is no tag
    NdefMessage ndefMsg = ndefTag.getNdefMessage();  // this reads the current NDEF message from the tag and consequently causes an IO operation
} catch (Exception e) {
    // there is no tag or communication with tag dropped
} finally {
    try {
        ndefTag.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

For non-NDEF tags, you would need to know how to access the tag using low-level commands though. But at least the connect test would work for any tag.

Comment: I've spoken to my customer and he says his carers leave the app via the Home key, as you suggested. They however do not long press the Home key to start the app, they click the app icon to start it. I'm not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: Rowland I can put the full Activity on my company's server for you to download if you'd like?

Comment: @turtleboy Re-starting an activity through the launcher icon may have the same effect -- though I'm not sure if the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` flag will be set in that case. However, you should be able to force a new instance to be created upon starting from launcher by setting the activity's `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` attribute to `true` in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: Rowland Other situations that can happen are as follows.  The carer scans in and out at Tag 'A'. She then goes to client 'B' and scans Tag 'B'. The app sends Tag 'A' info to server instead of Tag 'B' info. Another scenario is the carer will go to client 'A' and scans in and out. She will then go to client 'B' and scan in and out. Some time later the app will send Tag 'A' info to server. Have you any thoughts on this? If she is opening the app up 4 hours later for example, how can it send Tag 'A' info when all the variables that hold the Tag data have been set to null and

Comment: tag 'B' has been scanned since Tag 'A'?

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to test what you are suggesting. I've placed the code in [edit2] within the onCreate. I'm struggling to replicate Android killing the app. I've tried force closing the app, but when it is loaded again the launcher Activity is started which leads to the NFC Activity later. The Toast message 'not from history' is displayed. Also the long press home key does not work. how can i test what you are saying correctly?

Comment: @turtleboy So you have a "launcher activity"??? This sounds as if the NFC activity is not directly launched by the NFC service's intents but through the launcher activity!? If that's the case it would be important to know what that activity does and what activity/process launches the NFC activity.

Comment: I've posted the 2 activities in the Manifest in [Edit3]. EntryActivity is the launcher Activity and NfcScannerActivity is the one that processes the NFC tags. EntryActivity has nothing in it that processes NFC. it merely validates the user's credentials and downloads data from the server to configure app preferences. You can navigate from the EntryActivity to NfcScannerActivity but when that happens i set an IntentAction so the NFC code doesn't execute, it basically jumps into onResume. All the NFC code is in onCreate.

Comment: The NfcScannerActivity is directly launched by NFC service's intents, it is the only activity that has the intent filters to handle NFC

Comment: I forgot to ask you. The code you gave that tests the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0 should it only process the NFC tag if false? eg == 0

Comment: @turtleboy You are correct. This should be `==`. I've updated this.

Comment: I've placed code that sends an SMS to my phone if the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY is set. Otherwise the Tag is processed. I've given it to the customer so i'm just going to wait and see if i receive an SMS. Meanwhile is there a way i can replicate Android destroying the app whilst it is on the stack?

Comment: Use the Application Manager to force stop the app; then launching it from history will require it to be recreated.

Comment: @turtleboy It's really difficult to tell what is actually going wrong without knowing the transitions between the different activities, the activity stacks, etc. You might want to trace such information in a log file to be able to understand what happens. I would at least log every call to onCreate, onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop, onDestroy for *every* activity, log all intents that you send and receive, and possibly also log the result of GetTaskId and isTaskRoot.

Comment: @turtleboy I've updated my answer to give you a method to help you in detecting if you received a current intent or an old one (where the tag that caused it is not present). That method is certainly **not** an ideal solution though.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Thanks for the code! Would you just use the code that detects if the intent is new or old? will that suffice? Or should i use that code in conjunction with the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY check and the android:clearTaskOnLaunch=true in the Manifest?

Comment: @turtleboy I always use the check for FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY in my apps as this prevents many isues that I had in the past.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Actually i've just used the code in [edit4]. It seems to jump into the exception part of the code when i scan tag. It is though the try/catch fails when scanning a tag. any ideas why?

Comment: @MichaelRoland I've done some logging and it fails on the connect()

Comment: @turtleboy That's good, you should be able to do a rather generic presence detection then (using connect on `Ndef` for the NDEF case and on `NfcA`/`NfcB`/`NfcF`/`NfcV` (or only those of them that you actually use) for the TECH case.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Sorry, i'm not sure what you mean. I thought the code you have given above is using the connect() on an Ndef Object. The connect is failing. doesn't that mean it cannot read the tag?

Comment: @MichaelRoland Also i have a question about the level of Android that runs on the phone. All my customers that have Android 4.x and higher have no problems at all. The customer that is having all the problems is running Android 2.3.6. Are there any differences in how Android delivers intents to Activities or how NFC is processed between 4.x and 2.3.6?

Comment: @turtleboy I mean that this is okay when you only use tags that expose the Ndef tag technology. However, if you registered your TECH_DISCOVERED intent filter for other tag technologies than Ndef, you would also need to implement it for those additional technologies.

Comment: @turtleboy Yes, there certainly are differences between 4.x and 2.3.3+. I can't give you a list of these differences though.

Comment: @MichaelRoland The tags i'm scanning are Ndef, they have been formatted by the tagwriter app by NXP and have a payload. The connect method is still failing though.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Just to clarify then, do you think that 2.3.6 could handle NFC or the Android stack(redelivery of old intents) differently from 4.x. and thus be held accountable for the problems one of my customers is having(the one running 2.3.6)?

Comment: @turtleboy Is the connect method failing when there is *no* tag or when there *is* a tag present? With regard to 2.3.6, I really can't tell.

Comment: @MichaelRoland it's failing when the tag is present

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52691/discussion-between-michael-roland-and-turtleboy)

Comment: @MichaelRoland Hi. sorry i've been on holiday for a couple of weeks. i've started a new question regarding the failing connect.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994776/ndeftag-connect-not-connecting-to-tag

Answer (score 0):

Multiple scans/intents delivered to receiving Activity

Already answer accepted but better options is

add following flag while starting activity(by default activity is launched in default mode i.e. start new instance of activity)
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: You do realize that the NFC-related intents are generated by the Android system and that there is no way to add that flag to these intents?